# nethogs finds many connections without process ID

Tags: wifi, internet

Monitoring my network connections with nethogs (on ubuntu machine), I find many connections, which I cannot identify.

The columns are

```
PID  USER  DEV  SENT  RECEIVED
```

and most connections are owned by `root` that have no process ID, nor a device over which they are connected.

What are these connections? (Has my system been compromised?)

[image]

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [How to tell if mysterious programs in nethogs listing are malware?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91055/217726)

Comment: @JosephSible Thank you for the link. The answer on the linked question talks about HTTP connections on port 80. I guess these are the browser's HTTPS connections...?

Comment: How do you handle cross-site duplicates?